# display database content into browser using javascrichart.js and aspx c

Tags: javascript, c#, chart.js

I want to display database content into browser using chart js

Here is the aspx.cs file

```
public class DataPointChart
         {
 public string Argument { get; set; }
 public double Value { get; set; }
         }
 DataTable dtb = SelectStatistic(inputcbo)
 List<DataPointChart> statisticdata = new List<DataPointChart>{};
 foreach (DataRow dr in dtb.Rows){
 statisticdata.Add(new DataPointChart { Argument = dr["description"].ToString(), Value = dr["total"].ToInt() });
```

Here is the aspx file

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.4.0/chart.min.js"></script>
<div>
 <canvas id="bar"></canvas>
 <div>
```

How do I send database content on aspx.cs file into browser on aspx file ?